# How is this not a counter-example to the law of large numbers?

Tags: statistics, law-of-large-numbers

Let $\Omega = \{0,1\}$ and $X: \Omega \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ be a random variable s.t. $X = id$ with $E[X] = 0.5$ (i.e., $P(0) = 0.5 = P(1)$).

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, $\ldots$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $E[X_1] = E[X_2] = \ldots = 0.5 = E[X]$. In particular, let each of $X_i = id = X$.

**Assertion:** It seems to me necessarily the case that

$$
\overline{X}_n = {1 \over n} (X_1 + \ldots + X_n) = X
$$

This is since

$$
{1 \over n} (X_1(0) + \ldots + X_n(0)) = {1 \over n}0 = 0 = X(0)
$$

and

$$
{1 \over n} (X_1(1) + \ldots + X_n(1)) = {1 \over n}n = 1 = X(1)
$$

But this means that as $n \rightarrow \infty$, it is not the case that $\overline{X}_n \to E[X] = 0.5$.

**Question:** How is this not a counter-example to the law of large numbers?

Comment: Do you realize that taking each time the same variable is the least independent sequence possible ?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that it looks like you're confusing $X_i$ being equal to $X$ and $X_i$ being identically distributed to $X$.

Comment: @Rahul: I tried to show that $1/n(X_1 + \ldots + X_n)$ can only take values $0$ or $1$ above. How am I wrong? I don't understand how it can take value $1/2$.

Comment: @joriki: Do you mean that here $X = X_i$, but that the probability mass function for $X$ may fail to equal $X_i$?

Comment: @CaptainLama: What do you mean?

Comment: @No, that's not what I mean. I mean that the law of large numbers applies to independent identically distributed random variables whereas you're trying to apply it to identical random variables, which is something entirely different.

Comment: You say you take $X_i =X$ for all $i$. But that is the complete opposite of what it means to be independent variables, and in case this is not clear, one of the "i" in "iid" means independent. So your sequence just does not satisfy the hypothesis of the law of large numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The law of large numbers applies to independent identically distributed random variables, whereas you're trying to apply it to identical random variables, which are not independent.