# Does this context satisfy the hypothesis of the law of large numbers?

Tags: statistics, law-of-large-numbers

A precondition for the law of large numbers is that $X$ is a random variable with $X_1$, $X_2$, $\ldots$ being a sequence of i.i.d. random variables s.t. $E[X] = E[X_i]$.

Now suppose $X$ is the traditional random variable associated with tossing a fair coin. In particular, $X(0) = 0$, $X(1) = 1$, $P(X = 0) = P(X = 1) = 0.5$.

We can then assume that, in our case,

$X_1 = 1$ is the random variable associated with the coin coming coming up heads $X_0 = 0$ is the random variable associated with the coin coming up tails.

**Question:** Isn't it the case that

$$E[X_0] = 0.5*0 + 0.5*0 = 0 \ne 1 = 0.5*1 + 0.5*1 = E[X_1]$$

so that this context already cannot satisfy the hypothesis of the law of large numbers (since it violates the assumption that the expected value of all of the random variables from the sequence $X_i$ must be equal)? If so, this is confusing since a sequence of coin flips is frequently employed as a motivating example for the law of large numbers.

Comment: I don't understand your choice of notation. Why have you changed the index? For each $i$ you should have that $X_i=1$ occurs when the $i$th flip is heads and $X_i=0$ occurs when the $i$th flip is tails. There should be no change in the index for a given flip.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736238.

Comment: You seem to confuse random variables woth outcomes of random variables(the different values a random variable may attain)

Comment: @Bananach: I'm aware that my notation $X_1 =1$ and $X_0 = 0$ designate constant functions that are $1$ and $0$ everywhere. But I'm only writing it that way because other people are (and I presumed that constant functions are what they were talking about). For example Ian used that notation in his comment response.

Comment: There is no connection between the subscript $ i$of $ X_i $ and the values that this random variable can attain. In particular, each $ X_i $ can attain both 0 and 1 . Trust us,  you need to have a good look at the definition of random variables again. Also, by definition the expected value of identically distributed random variables is the same. You get the wrong answer because you pretend that X_0 is constant 0 and X_1 constant 1. They aren't.

Comment: So if $X_1 = 1$ doesn't mean $X_1$ is a constant function (as it would if we were to say $f = 1$ in another branch of mathematics), what does it mean?

Comment: @user1770201 $X_1=1$ is an event, which in formal probability theory is a subset of the probability space. It occurs with some probability but does not always occur.